# Libgdx Setting table column widths

Tags: libgdx

I want to set up a table within a scrollable area, but I also want to have a header row which does not scroll:

### [Header One|Header Two]

[Row 1 / 1|Row 1 / 2]
[Row 2 / 1|Row 2 / 2]
[Row 3 / 1|Row 3 / 2]

I have this working, however the column widths between the header table and the scrollable table do not line up. I am *currently* trying to use the following:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < headerColumnTable.getColumns(); i++)
    {
        headerColumnWidth = headerColumnTable.getColumnWidth( i );
        mainColumnWidth = mainTable.getColumnWidth( i );

        if (headerColumnWidth < mainColumnWidth)
            headerColumnTable.columnDefaults( i ).width( mainColumnWidth );
        else
            mainTable.columnDefaults( i ).width( headerColumnWidth );
    }
```

I cannot seem to affect the column width in any way.

I ***could*** fill the tables, get the columns widths, then clear the tables and refill them forcing the cell widths at that time, but this seems to be needlessly complex.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `pack` method? After the `for` loop, call the `pack` for both tables, that should cause it to recalculate the layouts.

Comment: Yes. I have tried pack(), validate(), invalidate(), and invalidateHierarchy(). If I use debug() I can see that the cells have been resized, but the table has not picked up on the new widths.

Comment: Ok, I fill the table plus the header table. I then get the widths between them (as per the code above), but I save the widths per column. Then I clear the tables and refill them using the column widths. And this works. This is only done once during the building of the stage, and usually will not have more than 50 items or so. The performance hit is not that great to actually **make** it work. Just complex. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have finally been able to check my old code - I didn't dynamically adjust the tables in mine, however I set sizes etc, and at the end was always a `pack()` call, so I'm surprised you say it didn't work...

Comment: Well, that's just it. If I fill the table and set the sizes, then the sizes take effect. But I cannot change the column width after the table is filled. And to be able to coordinate column widths between two tables you do need to dynamically change the widths. In the second pass, I set the width of the cell as I put it into the table.

Comment: If I don't forget, I'm going to test this when I get the time - I think the solution is to call the method `Table.layout()` after setting the new column widths.